# Create chainage points from hatch in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, linear-referencing

I have routes representing road centrelines created my geodatabase. I have hatched these features with point symbols and lables every 100m as shown below:
[image]

I would like to create a point feature class that replicates the hatch. That is, points every 100m along my routes with attributes containing route id and distance.

Is there a way that I can convert the hatch to points, retaining the attributes 
**OR** a tool that I can use create the point features with the attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the lines to points at fixed distance of 100m using [Create Points From Lines](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a2a41c8345e24ab6a9dd2ae215710b39) using ArcGIS. Or You can achieve the same thing if you already have QGIS with SAGA installed. Then under processing toolbox Go to `SAGA -> Shapes - Points -> Convert lines to points`. Then you can choose 100m in Distance field. But I am not sure if the created points will replicate the hatched points or not, but you test it and see the results.

Comment: Thanks ahmadhanb, I have been able to create the points along the line using a couple of different methods including Create Points From Lines but this is not all that I am after. I need to bring the distance and route id attributes across with the points.

Comment: If the points and the lines have common ID, then you can use join attribute based on that common ID, and if they share the same location, you can use spatial join. Or you can use intersect analysis to intersect the points with the lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an Excel table with route_id and km_values. and then use Arcgis Make Route Event Layer  with Event type = point. It will generate point layer in memory,and these points will be at the same place as hatches. And you can "save as" generated layer. But if you have hundreds of routes with thousands kilometers generating of excel files may become tedious routine.